# Bootstrap 3 issues with CSS background in header navbar

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

Here is my [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/oh69hq71/5/). As you can see, I am using Twitter Bootstrap 3 to create a simple 'header' nav menu.

There are two problems with this:

1. For the logo, I'm trying to use a CSS background instead of an `<img/>` tag, and its either not rendering, or the box/window for the background is too small to display the actual logo; and
2. The nav menu is too "tall"; meaning I want it to be shorter and "hug" the menu links more closely. You'll notice there's a considerable amount of gray underneath all the links and that the 'Sign in' link needs to be horizontally aligned with the green 'Sign up' button

Per the logo issue, you'll notice that I'm trying to make the width bigger (50%), but the browser does not seem to be responding. It's also worth mentioning that `/images/mylogo.png` *is* a valid URL and that when I use an `<img/>` tag instead of the `<a>`/CSS background, the logo displays just fine.

Per the nav menu height issue, I *suspect* it may have something to do with this part:

```
<!-- But here I'm not explicitly setting the height and so perhaps TB3 is setting one for me...? -->
<div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
    ...
</div>
```

But I can't tell for sure. Anybody see where I'm going awry?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default header-height">
  <div class="container-fluid header-height">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">WebSiteName</a>
    </div>
    <div>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Page 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Page 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Page 3</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

and then write this css in other file and attach to your html file

```
.header-height {
    height: 30px;
}

.navbar-brand {
    background: url(...);
    background-size: 50%;
    padding: ??; /* padding for vertical align */
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Mahdy Aslamy (+1) - I'll take a look at this tonight and will get back to you with feedback. Any chance you can explain the 30,000 ft view of what you did and why it works? Also just to be clear, I only want the logo to show up in the top-left corner of my header/navbar, not be a "background image" that spans the entire navbar.

Comment: thanks, (i don't understand English very well) i just set a background for div as brand image and set size to decrease image size to be correct and set height for header and you can change. if this is repetitive set background-repeat: no-repeat;

Comment: OK @Mahdy Aslamy (+1) - please see my [updated jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/oh69hq71/2/). As you can see, two problems still persist: (1) the image logo, which I specify as being **250x150**, is still showing up too small; and (2) the "*Sign in*" link is still not centering vertically inside the navbar. Any ideas? Thanks again so much!!!

Comment: hi, i update your code. for center vertically your text set padding-top for <a> tag with CSS. https://jsfiddle.net/oh69hq71/4/

Comment: Thanks again, I think we're *almost* there! Please see my [edit](https://jsfiddle.net/oh69hq71/5/) which is the same as your last one, except I resized the image to be smaller.  **See how there is still some grey padding *below* the image?** I need that to be gone!, and I need the entire nav menu to be vertically centered, any ideas how? Thanks again!

Comment: hi, there are two way first change .navbar-header padding or change <a> tag in your form padding. check it https://jsfiddle.net/oh69hq71/7/